# What is Hamilton's rule for multiple generations?

Tags: evolution, population-genetics, evolutionary-game-theory

What is Hamilton's rule as it applies to multiple generations?  Is it that the lineage success given up by the actor must be exceeded by the lineage success acquired times the relatedness between actor and acquirers?  How is this represented?